# Spaceship returning to earth after generations

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the title of a short movie where a spaceship with humans onboard is returning to earth after many generations. The humans that were left  behind on earth have created a utopian society and feel threatened by the return of the others ,which were the violent ones.

I watched this many years ago and I not even sure if it's a short film...

Thanx

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it?  What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195284/man-awaken-from-suspended-animation-to-stop-an-asteroid-heading-towards-earth-w (which is newer but has a more complete question and answer)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are seeking the Twilight Zone Episode [Wiki Quarantine (The Twilight Zone)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_(The_Twilight_Zone)).

Points that match:

"A short movie"

> The episode is ~1 hour broadcast.

The humans left on Earth left behind have created a utopian society

> Matthew (protagonist) begins learning more and more about the agrarian post-apocalypse community where Sarah lives. Every need there is met through genetic engineering, psionics, and super-science in harmony with Nature

Spaceship with humans aboard is returning

> When the meteor makes a course correction upon reaching orbit, Matthew discovers that it isn't a meteor coming, but a United States spacecraft.

...and feel threatened by the return of the others ,which were the violent ones.

> Sarah explains that the community is threatened by the instigators of the war, who are returning to Earth. They left the Earth during the catastrophic war they started to save their own lives and perpetuate their power